# How to get the current script to read off computer names off a txt file located on c:\

Tags: powershell

I currently have this script working but only able to get it to run locally, I would like to have it read a text file that would be stored on c:\List_of_PCs.txt that would have computer names that it would also run the same script on. That way I can update the text file instead of modify the code.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

# Get all users 
$users = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users"

# Loop through users and delete the Teams file
$users | ForEach-Object {
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\Cache\f*" -Force 
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\Application Cache\Cache\f*" -Force 
}
```

Any help on this I've tried multiple things every which way, I'm sure this is something simple but I'm still very new to PowerShell.

Comment: Are you asking about reading from a file or running on a remote computer? Your title suggests the first option, but the first sentence in the body suggests you have issues executing it remotely.

Comment: I would be reading the PC names off a text file for remote computers on the same network.

Comment: If you just need to the content of the file, use `Get-Content`. If the issue is running the script remotely, Then I would suggest running `Set-ExecutionPolicy` before you try and run the script. If `Set-ExecutionPolicy` is part of the script, it won't run, because your execution policy is initially Restricted which will prevent that line from running.

Comment: I've tried running Get-Content in the past which would list the PC names but I believe it did not work due to myself not having the knowledge to tie the commands listed after that to the computer names listed. It would run locally on my computer instead

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

Requires PowerShell remoting to be enabled and using an account that is an admin on the remote computer

```
$ComputerList = Import-Csv -Path 'c:\List_of_PCs.txt'


$ComputerList | % { 
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
        # Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned # this is something that should be set via GPO for all systems, not your script, so that it is centrally controlled and monitored.

        # Get all users 
        $users = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users"

        # Loop through users and delete the Teams file
        $users | ForEach-Object {
        Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\Cache\f*" -Force 
        Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\$($_.Name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\Application Cache\Cache\f*" -Force 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but no luck. On the bright side thou no errors.

Comment: Hummm..  what do you mean by this... "Tried this but no luck". The target never responded? / The keys were never removed?, Are you running this as the admin on the target? Did you pass credentials to the target that is an admin? What does you csv look like?

Comment: Apologies for not being more detailed, 

The keys were not removed, also in PS it ran as if it were successful with no red errors. I'am running as an admin in PS locally. Could you please let me know if that is not the same as running as admin on the target. On the csv file where it is reading from it has info on A1 and A2. Both are computer names.

Comment: If A1 and B1 are both computer names are yo saying that are both different? You have to choose one column at a time. That Import-Csv, is going to bring in both, as separate columns, which means this ComputerName $_ has to be change to the right column ComputerName $A1 or ComputerName $A2. Hence why I asked that your file looks like. You must use creds that is an admin on the remote host. Running as admin locally does not equate to running as admin on the remote host, unless you are the admin on the remote host using the same creds you are logged on as.